# Tensorflow model prediction produce results more than the data provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, prediction

I have created a tensorflow model using tensorflow High level API tf.estimator.Estimator based on this [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers). Instead of downloading MNIST data from internet I read it from a local CSV file. and it was working fine. However, when I migrated the code to use tf.contrib.learn.Estimator I had a problem with the number of predictions. My test_data is 28000 images, but I get back 28032 predictions as a result of model prediction.

Prediction code:

```
predict_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": test_data},
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False)

predictions = list(mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))
```

test_data is array of shape (28000,28,28,1)
but len(predictions) = 28032
Anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: I'd pass a batch size to `numpy_input_fn` which divides your dataset evenly if it's important that the returned predictions have exactly the same number of elements (default is 128). You could also just trim away the repeated predictions (last 32).

Comment: @AllenLavoie thanks passing a batch size of 100 seems to solve the problem. It appears that even I have specified num_epochs=1, it reused 32 examples to complete the last batch to 128, but when I use 100 it will not to do that.

Comment: This is a pretty general annoyance with batching and the concept of epochs. If it could yield a batch of something other than 128, it would have to set the shape information for its output to be unknown for the batch dimension. In a parallel universe there's someone asking about why the shape of `numpy_input_fn`'s output is undefined when they specifically told it to be 128 (or if executing eagerly, why one batch isn't size 128). Some functions have `allow_smaller_final_batch` flags.